# Active_Admin routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activeadmin, before-filter

I have installed Active_Admin gem in my app but I have a filter on my application so the only page you can get to is the log in page. When I try to access the active_admin page it routes me to my log in page of my application, not my admin log in. When I log into my application I can then access the active_admin log in page. My question is where I would put my skip_before_filter statement in this gem? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would put the skip filter in your Application Controller. This could be in a lib/my_active_admin.rb. Then require 'my_active_admin' in applications_controller before the ApplicationControllers definition.

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class ResourceController < BaseController
    before_filter :my_filter

    protected

    def my_filter
      <logic here>
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, this fixes the issue but it also opens my entire application up. Since the controller for the active_admin is actually located in the gems folder, I don't know how to set up the :except statement for that specified controller. Any ideas on how to set up an :except statement on a path C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\activeadmin-0.4.4\app\views\active_admin. Any ideas?

Comment: I have added code, but cannot try/ test myself. Does it help?

Comment: This code was partially right, and it helped. I setup to skip the before filter on the application controller and then set the before filter on every other controller. I know this is a long work around, but this application isn't huge so it works for this. You can't specify a before filter in the ActiveAdmin gem for some reason. Thank you for your help.